# Prevent filtering on dc.js bar chart until mouse-up event

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using dc.js with a fairly large dataset, and finding that filtering using the bar chart is quite slow and often "sticks" when dragging the brush.

We are also triggering some additional processing using a callback on the "filtered" event, which is partly to blame for slowing it down.

```
chart.on("filtered", function() {
    //additional data processing functions called here
});
```

We have been able to improve performace somewhat using the "postRender" event and moving the callback to the mouseup event. So we're now only calling our post-processing functions once, rather than repeatedly when the brush is dragged. (Thanks to this answer: [How to handle mouseout event on DC range graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523772/how-to-handle-mouseout-event-on-dc-range-graph))

```
chart.on('postRender', function() {
    chart.select('.brush').on("mouseup", function() {
        //additional data processing functions called here
    });
});
```

However, filtering using the brush is still quite "sticky" and slow. The reason for the slow performance is that dc.js re-filters the crossfilter data as soon as the user drags the brush. So if the user holds down the mouse button and makes several dragging moves it's repeatedly re-filtering.

Is there a way to tell dc.js to re-filter only after mouseup? I would have thought this is a common problem when using larger data sets, but I can't find anything in the docs.

The obvious alternative is to disable the brush on the chart, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: There is a workaround on this issue: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/627. It should be customizable.

Answer (score 2):

Have you updated to 2.0.0-beta.19? That contains a big fix to filtering that gets rid of the old behavior where the dimension filter would be completely reset while dragging. It should now filter incrementally.